# how to display data from mysql in jquery tabs without refreshing the page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-tabs

I have a page where there will be many tabs and i want to display data in each tab which is extracted from mysql database. I need this in jquery without refreshing the page just clicking on the tabs the data to be displayed concenrned with the person id.

Can anyone please give me idea how to do this one in jquery

Thanks in advance,

Ramsai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example on the JQuery demos site that implements almost this exact scenario:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax.  The JQuery UI library lets you write the tab sources as normal hrefs, and it converts them to AJAX-enabled tabs.  So all you'd have to do is implement each tab as a separate URL/query string, pulling from the MySql source as needed.

Answer (score 1):

it's rely simple. All you need to do is ajax method with following attributes :

client side:

jquery code with ajax method

1.) url to which the php code will iterate your mysql database
2.) data to be sended. will be inside data attribute in json form.
3.) write methods after you receive a response i.e. json too.

server side with php/mysql

1.) get data with $_GET method . in your case person id
2.) look into db.
3.) encode using echo json_encode(->data<-);

for more info. please refer:

[This describes the jquery .ajax method. i will assume you r aware of php and mysql](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thank you very much kishan thobhani